# On page load, using a delay causes site to fail in Edge 13

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-edge, velocity.js

I'm trying to implement a simple loading screen which fades out after page load using jQuery's $(window).load() feature. I added a small delay of 800ms in case the page loads too fast to ensure the loading screen has some time to present itself to the user, so as not to look like an error.

However regardless of HOW I add a delay (I've tried both setTimeout() and velocity.js built-in delay option) the page will fail once .load() runs the function and I get this message:

[image: Edge 13 - Error]

No console errors or anything out of the ordinary with the code. You can see this in action here: http://splash.resa.nickdimatteo.com

Comment: The page appears to be loading correctly

Comment: Probably an issue with that specific version of edge, I'm using version 20 and page loads perfectly

Comment: That makes sense, thanks guys!